# A script way to read through an email line by line by avoiding the = signs automatically breaking long lines

Tags: linux, bash, email

I am using getamil to retrieve email messages.
I have a directory called "new" under "~/bak/mail" to which the emails are going.
Every new email I receive is created as a file with ".ubuntu" extension under the "~/bak/mail/new" directory.

When I just "cat" each file, it is not properly displayed as it has all sort of headers, etc.
e.g: 
Delivered-To:, Received:, Authentication-Results:, etc.

I don't really care about parsing the headers properly, but more concerned about the fact that long lines are broken using an equal sign character (=).
So a line that doesn't have an equal sign at all in the original message looks like this:

```
you have received this email message since you are subscribed to the public group=

 "Customers" public group.
```

when going through the file line by line or "cat"ing the file in the shell, instead of

```
you have received this email message since you are subscribed to the public group "Customers" public group.
```

as it appears in the mail client.

I am writing a script in which I'm parsing the file manually, but I want to see the line as a line without the = sign, so reading the file line by line doesn't do the trick, nor "cat"ing the file... because in these ways I encounter shorter lines terminated by = sign.

How can I go over such an email file, line by line in a script, but seeing lines as full lines, not broken with = signs?

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a representative sample of your input and the desired output.

Comment: @TomFenech, Done. Hope it's better now! Thank you.

Comment: Still not clear to me if you want to create `=` after public group, or you want to remove the equal sign.. In addition I would not recommend creating a new file for every mail. At some point you will need huge disk amount and you can get a lack of Inodes. There is a reason to use file types like `.mbox` or `spool mail`

Comment: @suleiman I edited that part again, Sorry that I wasn't able to be clear the first/second times. I don't want the = they are there because it's the way email messages are built I suppose... I want to read the line as a whole and not have those = signs. I read online and I'm not the only one that encountered = signes breaking long lines in email raw files.

Comment: Have you tried decoding the quoted printable-encoded content yet?

Comment: Even if it not extremely complex, correct processing of a mail message is IMHO beyond the capabilities of a shell script and would be better achieved using Python, Perl, Ruby or any other procedural language...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-AbramsI I think that's essentially what I was trying to ask - how do I decode it to appear without the = signs in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but the following removes a linebreak preceded by an =

```
cat test | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/=\n/test/g'
```

For a good explanation on the flags and such:
http://www.canbike.org/information-technology/sed-delete-carriage-returns-and-linefeeds-crlf.html

*Edit: To clarify it replaces the linebreak and '=' and literally so if there's whitespace it won't work. If there is whitespace you can try:

```
cat test | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/=[[:blank:]]*\n/ /g'
```

That will remove an '=' with any amount of (and only) tabs/spaces between the = and a break. I kind of doubt any are there though.

Comment: I came up with the same solution, but there is an empty line between the text. I cant get arround that neither. `sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/=\n/ /;ta' -e 'P;D'`

Comment: Try 
cat test | sed '/^$/d' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/=\n/ /g'

Comment: Eh that's sloppy. Sorry bit of a scrub. In my syntax I can simply double the \n i.e. cat test | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/=\n\n/ /g' 
It's not having the same effect going directly through sed though, not sure why.

Comment: Thank you for trying, but that's not what I'm after. Like I said - I parse the file line by line so in each iteration I don't yet "see" the next line.
I'd like to find a way to maybe decode the email first and then read it line by line so I won't have to deal with text manipulations. By the way, there can also be equal signs both at the beginning or at end of a line so I certainly don't want to remove all of them anyway.